# Proofs for the properties of $\mu(\sigma)$, the order of $\zeta(s)$

Tags: soft-question, proof-explanation, book-recommendation, riemann-zeta

The following is a text from Section 5.1 of Titchmarsh's book *The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function*:

*For each $\sigma$ we define a number $\mu(\sigma)$ as the lower bound of numbers $\xi$ such that $\zeta(\sigma + it) = O (|t|^{\xi})$. It follows from the general theory of Dirichlet series that, as a function of $\sigma$, $\mu(\sigma)$ is continuous, non-increasing, and convex downwards in the sense that no arc of the curve $y = \mu(\sigma)$ has any point above its chord; also $\mu(\sigma)$ is never negative.*

The author cites to his other book *Theory of Functions* for the proofs. This book was useful any other time when a subject was cited, but for this part I couldn't understand the proofs. A reference for proofs of the claims above about $\mu(\sigma)$ would be much appreciated, especially a proof for the convexity.  I could not find some book or lecture notes for this.

Comment: what is unclear in the proof in the Titchmarsh book page 181?; one applies the three-line theorem to $\zeta(s)/(-is)^{as+b}$ where one takes $a,b$ so the linear function $as+b$ takes the value $\mu(\sigma_1)+\epsilon$ at $\sigma_1$ and $\mu(\sigma_2)+\epsilon$ at $\sigma_2$; the functional equation and usual asymptotics for $\gamma$ show that $\mu(\sigma)=1/2-\sigma, \sigma \le 0$ since obviously $\mu(\sigma)=0, \sigma >1$ which is trivially true for any Dirichlet series in its absolute convergent half plane, hence we can restrict to $0< \sigma_1 <\sigma_2<1$ and everything easily checks out

Comment: @Conrad, To my understanding I need to study Sec-9.41 but it cites to Sec-5.65 and Sec-5.65 refers to Sec-5.61 for preliminary but Sec-5.61 is not clear. That's how I could not understand. I am a voracious reader and I don't mind length generally. But it looks that I need to study chapters of the book for Sec-5.61 and then unfortunately I'll have less time left for Titchmarsh's RZF book to finish which I have a deadline for that.

Comment: regardless of how you want to approach it, you need to go through the strip version of Phragmen-Lindelof and its follow-up, the three lines theorem which essentially says that if $f$ is bounded on a vertical strip then the vertical bounds are logarithmically convex; applying the above (P-L first to conclude boundness on the strip from boundness on end lines and three lines to conclude logarithmic convexity) to  $\zeta(s)/(-is)^{as+b}$ gives you the result; there are no shortcuts

Comment: @Conrad, I want a rigorous study so I will study preliminaries from the book as much as possible unless I knew another source for short-cut learning. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Conrad, not relevant to this question but I was wondering if you know a book that explains Weyl-Hardy-Littlewood method for $O(t^{\frac16} \log^{\frac23} t)$ for $\zeta$? Sections 3.5 to 3.8 (inclusive) of Titchmarsh's book are written too much unclear. Thanks.

Comment: the book by Graham and Kolesnik on Van Der Corput method of exponential sums is a good one for these type of question https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/van-der-corputs-method-of-exponential-sums/8902E3E7B86C7A91B2F321230E55B44B

Comment: @Conrad, I couldn't find an ebook for the book and my university library does not have it :(